# Missing return type warning typescript generated

Tags: typescript

I know this is asked many times but most of them tell to disable this warning, so what this warning means according to me is linter is unable to find return statement. Also, if i change return curly brackets with parenthesis linter stops complaining but this causes more error in that line.Now the warning:- Missing return type on function.eslint@typescript-eslint/explicit-module-boundary-types it is on async () => .

```
export const connectDatabase = async () => {
  const client = await MongoClient.connect(url, {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
  });
  const db = client.db("graphql");

  return {
    listings: db.collection("listing"),
  };
};
```

Comment: `async (): Promise<{listings: Array<TypeHere>}> => {....` is what it is expecting. If you want to forgo any type of type checking you could make it `any` but then you negate the benefits of type checking.

Comment: Thanks it solved the issue.